# Compiling Linux code in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, compilation, cross-platform

We are developing our application for Linux platform. We are using Visual Studio 2012/2010 as IDE. But to compile we need to go back and forth from Windows to Linux. Is there any way to use g++ (gcc) in Visual Studio as compiler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dupe-linked questions is **half a decade old**, though. Not voting for close.

Comment: Are you writing code which is platform/compiler specific? If no then I suggest you use CMake.

Comment: Unfortunately my answer is Yes. I am writing Platform Specific code.